# Is it possible to us a protocol for the type in UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am writing a UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource to populate a UICollectionView.

That looks like this right now:

```
dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, SomeDataItemClass>( ... )
```

However the `SomeDataItemClass` is a NSManagedObject from CoreData, and I'd like a bit more flexibility in giving this type of object to the datasource so that I can detach the presentation from the CoreData class a bit. My first inclination is to just create a protocol for the properties that configure the collection view cells, then I can have my CoreData managed object class implement the protocol, and I will also be free to implement that protocol on any other objects I might want to be represented that don't necessarily come from CoreData.

So I made something like:

```
protocol PresentableItem: Hashable {
 var title: String? { get }
 ...
}
```

And I use presentable item when creating the data source:

```
dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, PresentableItem >( ... )
```

... coming from Objective-C I thought this would be a slam dunk... but I get the error `Type 'any PresentableItem' cannot conform to 'Hashable'`... which I've tried to understand and the best I can find out is that in this use-case, it doesn't matter that my protocol inherits the Hashable protocol.

Is there a way to accomplish what I need here? Or should I just have my data objects vend a struct for cell configuration and use the struct identity here instead of the protocol perhaps?

Advice very much appreciated!